# Array interpolation

Tags: java, arrays, interpolation

Before I start, please accept my apologies that I'm not a mathematician and don't really know the proper names for what I'm trying to do... ;) Pointers to any plain-English explanations that might help would be most appreciated (as I'm purely Googling at the moment based upon what I *think* the solution *might* be).

If have a multi-dimensionsal array of source values and wanted to upscale that array by a factor of *n*, I *think* that what I'd need to use is [Bicubic Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) Certainly the image top right on that page is representative of what I'm aiming for - creating a graduated flow of values between the underlying source data points, based upon the value(s) of their surrounding neighbours. I completely accept that by not increasing the volume of data I am not increasing the resolution of the data; merely blurring the edges.

Something akin to going from this;

[image: Source grid]

to this (and beyond);

[image: Target grid]

Following the [link within the Wikipedia article gives me a (supposed) example implementation](http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic) of what I'm striving for, but if it does I fear I'm currently missing the logical leap to get myself there. When I call getValue(source, 0.5, 0.5) on the BicubicInterpolator, what am I getting back? I *thought* that if I gave an x/y of (0.0,0.0) I would get back the bottom-left value of the grid and if I looked at (1,1) I would get top-right, and any value between would give me the specified position within the interpolated grid.

```
double[][] source  = new double[][] {{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}};
BicubicInterpolator bi = new BicubicInterpolator();
for (double idx = 0; idx <= 1; idx += 0.1) {
  LOG.info("Result (" + String.format("%3.1f", idx) + ", " + String.format("%3.1f", idx) + ") : " + bi.getValue(source, idx, idx));         
}
```

The output for a diagonal line across my source grid however is;

```
Result (0.0, 0.0) : 2.0
Result (0.1, 0.1) : 2.08222625
Result (0.2, 0.2) : 2.128
Result (0.3, 0.3) : 2.13747125
Result (0.4, 0.4) : 2.11424
Result (0.5, 0.5) : 2.06640625
Result (0.6, 0.6) : 2.00672
Result (0.7, 0.7) : 1.9518312500000001
Result (0.8, 0.8) : 1.92064
Result (0.9, 0.9) : 1.93174625
Result (1.0, 1.0) : 2.0
```

I'm confused because the diagonals go from 1 to 3 and from 1 to 2; there's nothing going from 2 to 2 with very little (overall) variation. Am I completely mis-understanding things?

---

**EDIT :** Following Peter's suggestion to expand the boundary for analysis, the grid can now be generated as a quick'n'dirty upscale to a 30x30 matrix;

[image: Grid from Peter's answer]

Now that what's going on is making a bit more sense, I can see that I need to consider a few additional things;

- Control the overshoot (seen in the middle of the grid where the source has a block of four cells with a value of 2, but the interpolated value peaks at 2.2)
- Cater for blank values in the source grid and have them treated as blanks, rather than zero, so that they don't skew the calculation
- Be prepare to be told I'm on a fool's errand and that a different solution is needed
- See if this was what the customer thought they actually wanted when they said "*make it less blocky*"

Comment: So how did you turn your original array into the interpolated array? given that  double[][] source = new double[][]{{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}}; was your original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you assume the "outside" temperature is the same as the outer most ring of values, and you want to shift which port of the grid you are considering...

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    double[][] source = new double[][]{{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}};
    BicubicInterpolator bi = new BicubicInterpolator();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        double idx = i / 10.0;
        System.out.printf("Result (%3.1f, %3.1f) : %3.1f%n", idx, idx, bi.getValue(source, idx, idx));
    }
}

public static class CubicInterpolator {
    public static double getValue(double[] p, double x) {
        int xi = (int) x;
        x -= xi;
        double p0 = p[Math.max(0, xi - 1)];
        double p1 = p[xi];
        double p2 = p[Math.min(p.length - 1,xi + 1)];
        double p3 = p[Math.min(p.length - 1, xi + 2)];
        return p1 + 0.5 * x * (p2 - p0 + x * (2.0 * p0 - 5.0 * p1 + 4.0 * p2 - p3 + x * (3.0 * (p1 - p2) + p3 - p0)));
    }
}

public static class BicubicInterpolator extends CubicInterpolator {
    private double[] arr = new double[4];

    public double getValue(double[][] p, double x, double y) {
        int xi = (int) x;
        x -= xi;
        arr[0] = getValue(p[Math.max(0, xi - 1)], y);
        arr[1] = getValue(p[xi], y);
        arr[2] = getValue(p[Math.min(p.length - 1,xi + 1)], y);
        arr[3] = getValue(p[Math.min(p.length - 1, xi + 2)], y);
        return getValue(arr, x+ 1);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Result (0.0, 0.0) : 1.0
Result (0.1, 0.1) : 1.0
Result (0.2, 0.2) : 1.0
Result (0.3, 0.3) : 1.1
Result (0.4, 0.4) : 1.1
Result (0.5, 0.5) : 1.3
Result (0.6, 0.6) : 1.4
Result (0.7, 0.7) : 1.6
Result (0.8, 0.8) : 1.7
Result (0.9, 0.9) : 1.9
Result (1.0, 1.0) : 2.0
Result (1.1, 1.1) : 2.1
Result (1.2, 1.2) : 2.1
Result (1.3, 1.3) : 2.1
Result (1.4, 1.4) : 2.1
Result (1.5, 1.5) : 2.1
Result (1.6, 1.6) : 2.0
Result (1.7, 1.7) : 2.0
Result (1.8, 1.8) : 1.9
Result (1.9, 1.9) : 1.9
Result (2.0, 2.0) : 2.0
Result (2.1, 2.1) : 2.1
Result (2.2, 2.2) : 2.3
Result (2.3, 2.3) : 2.5
Result (2.4, 2.4) : 2.7
Result (2.5, 2.5) : 2.8
Result (2.6, 2.6) : 2.9
Result (2.7, 2.7) : 3.0
Result (2.8, 2.8) : 3.0
Result (2.9, 2.9) : 3.0
Result (3.0, 3.0) : 3.0
```

---

Looking at how this works, you have a 2x2 grid of inside values and a 4x4 square outside it for outside values. the (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) values map the diagonal between 2 (in cell 2,2) and 2 (in cell 3,3) using the outer values to help interpolate the values.

```
double[][] source = new double[][]{{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}};
BicubicInterpolator bi = new BicubicInterpolator();
for (int i = -10; i <= 20; i++) {
    double idx = i / 10.0;
    System.out.printf("Result (%3.1f, %3.1f) : %3.1f%n", idx, idx, bi.getValue(source, idx, idx));
}
```

prints

```
Result (-1.0, -1.0) : -5.0
Result (-0.9, -0.9) : -2.8
Result (-0.8, -0.8) : -1.2
Result (-0.7, -0.7) : -0.2
Result (-0.6, -0.6) : 0.5
Result (-0.5, -0.5) : 1.0
Result (-0.4, -0.4) : 1.3
Result (-0.3, -0.3) : 1.5
Result (-0.2, -0.2) : 1.7
Result (-0.1, -0.1) : 1.9
Result (0.0, 0.0) : 2.0
Result (0.1, 0.1) : 2.1
Result (0.2, 0.2) : 2.1
Result (0.3, 0.3) : 2.1
Result (0.4, 0.4) : 2.1
Result (0.5, 0.5) : 2.1
Result (0.6, 0.6) : 2.0
Result (0.7, 0.7) : 2.0
Result (0.8, 0.8) : 1.9
Result (0.9, 0.9) : 1.9
Result (1.0, 1.0) : 2.0
Result (1.1, 1.1) : 2.1
Result (1.2, 1.2) : 2.3
Result (1.3, 1.3) : 2.5
Result (1.4, 1.4) : 2.7
Result (1.5, 1.5) : 2.8
Result (1.6, 1.6) : 2.7
Result (1.7, 1.7) : 2.1
Result (1.8, 1.8) : 0.9
Result (1.9, 1.9) : -1.4
Result (2.0, 2.0) : -5.0
```

Comment: how did you turn your original array into the interpolated array? given that double[][] source = new double[][]{{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}}; was your original.