# How can I interpolate empty values of partially-filled array?

Tags: c#

I have array that is partially filled, how can I fill empty values with estimates based on other values? 
I'm finding myself doing fugly nested loop monsters with lots of integers keeping indexes and would not like to use that approach.

Array could look like this (size of dimensions of array is not same every time, also values are mostly random):

```
double[,] xyarray = new double[4,3] {{10,100,1000},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{40,400,4000}};
```

And I would like to automatically calculate and fill these 0-values with estimates like this:

```
{{10,100,1000}{20,200,2000}{30,300,3000}{40,400,4000}}
```

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is interpolation

Comment: Yes thanks! That helped me find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668821/array-interpolation
This question could probably be marked as duplicate.